# Azure AI Search: Adding a vector field causes the index to appear empty

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-ai, azure-ai-search

I am trying to create an index with indexer and skillset in Azure AI Search with a datasource connected to adlsgen2. Going through the import data wizard works fine, and creates the index, indexer, and skillset with a few skills such as OCR and merge.

The problem arises when I add a vector field. I add it with the following config:

Collection(Edm.Single)
Retrievable
Dimensions: 1536
Create the vectorizer and algorithm without changing the config from the default.

Simply adding this field to the index causes the index to always return empty. The indexer runs and says it is successful, but the index will be empty.

As mentioned, running everything the same but without that field is fine and the index is populated with information. I have not yet mapped the vector field to anything, it is just there.

There is a warning on the indexer run that may have something to do with it:
This ADLS Gen2 indexer maps the property 'metadata_storage_path' to the index key, which may not reindex documents if directories are renamed. Update the 'LastModified' timestamps for all the blobs in the directory to ensure they get reindexed.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Did you reset your indexer after adding the new field? Did you also add a skill to generate the vector embedding, and then either an outputFieldMapping or indexProjections to map that embedding to the search index? Highly recommend using the "Import and Vectorize Data" experience in the portal so that this all just gets set up automatically for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-portal-import-vectors

Comment: We did reset the indexer, we even tried adding the field during the setup wizard, it seems that having the field stops it indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can't repro the issue. I used the Import data wizard to index 4 PDFs from adls gen2, and then added a vector field, type collection(edm.string), dimensions 1536, with a vector profile (this step is required), but no vectorizer (it's optional). Reset and reran the indexer, and I got the same content the second time around. Having an empty vector field in the index didn't break the adls gen2 indexer for me or generate an empty index.

Comment: follow up question -- does the "Import and vectorize data" wizard work for you?  I recall reading that a small subset of old search services don't support vectors. Just wondering if that could be the issue.